# How to globally import css styles in Vue properly?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

i have a scss file containing few classess. Every time i save the file, corresponding css files are generated. I have thought that i just need to import a result css in main.js file to use it in my whole application. For example, let's assume that i have a following css class contained in index.scss:

```
.button-label {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I imported it's file in main.js like this:

```
import "@/assets/styles/index.css";

...

const vm = new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  Snotify,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");

export default vm;
```

I would expect, that now i can use button-label class in every component i have in my application. Unfortunately it doesn't work. It seems like the given classes are being ignored. Do i have to additionally import the mentioned file in my components? What am i doing wrong? How to properly globally import stylesheets? Thanks for any help. My index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can link to the outputted CSS in your `index.html` with a normal `style` tag

Comment: Well, i ahve tried to import it there with <link> tag, and it still has not worked. Maybe something is wrong with my css? The whole file looks like this https://pasteboard.co/JALrGHd.png

Comment: Could you add `index.html` and your file structure to the post?

Comment: Sure, ive attached index.html file (but with no linking) to the post. Here's my structure: https://pasteboard.co/JALx5yn.png

Comment: Assuming `index.min.css` holds all your styles, did you link to `../src/assets/styles/index.min.css`?

Comment: No i've linked it like, that <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/assets/styles/index.css"/>

Comment: Pointing to index.min.css nothing changed :(

Comment: Might need to be in the same directory. I have my Sass compile to a single CSS file inside `public` and just link to that which works fine

Answer (score 0):

I did not worked with SCSS files in my vue components, but for my single file component (vue SFC) I added the link of my global stylesheet in the App.vue (main template file) like below and it works:

```
<style src="../public/styles/style.css"></style>
```

in my file structure App.vue is in the "src" folder and index.html and styleseets are in the "public" folder, but I don't think that was important.